# Kotlin testing dispatch work to multipele channels

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I currently have made some code which sends messages to x amount of channels based on the amount of workers that is set. It seems to work correctly but when I try to test it, it gets stuck when I don't add a delay which seems a bit hacky.

My channel dispatcher:

```
fun <INPUT_TYPE, OUTPUT_TYPE> CoroutineScope.dispatchWorkConcurrently(
    inputChannel: ReceiveChannel<INPUT_TYPE>,
    processWork: suspend (INPUT_TYPE, SendChannel<OUTPUT_TYPE>) -> Unit,
    logger: Logger,
    nameOfWorkers: String,
    maxWorkers: Int,
    workerCounter: AtomicInteger
): ReceiveChannel<OUTPUT_TYPE> {
    val coroutineScope = this + SupervisorJob()

    suspend fun launchWorker(
        input: Channel<INPUT_TYPE>,
        output: Channel<OUTPUT_TYPE>
    ) {
        val coroutineExceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, throwable ->
            workerCounter.decrementAndGet()
            logger.error("Exception in $nameOfWorkers: ${throwable.localizedMessage}")
        }
        val newCounterValue = workerCounter.incrementAndGet()
        coroutineScope.launch(coroutineExceptionHandler + CoroutineName("$nameOfWorkers $newCounterValue")) {
            for (work in input) {
                processWork(work, output)
            }
        }
    }

    val internalChannel = Channel<INPUT_TYPE>()
    val outputChannel = Channel<OUTPUT_TYPE>()

    coroutineScope.launch {
        for (message in inputChannel) {
            if (!internalChannel.trySend(message).isSuccess) {
                val allowedToLaunchNewWorker = workerCounter.get() < maxWorkers
                if (allowedToLaunchNewWorker) {
                    launchWorker(internalChannel, outputChannel)
                }

                internalChannel.send(message)
            }
        }
    }

    return outputChannel
}
```

Unit test:

```
@Test
fun `correctly dispatch jobs with multipele workers`() = runBlocking {
    val charPool : List<Char> = ('a'..'z').toList()
    val count = AtomicInteger(0);
    suspend fun processWork(message: Char, output: SendChannel<String>) {
        delay(1)
        println("Does some work with: $message")
        count.getAndIncrement()
    }

    this.dispatchWorkConcurrently(
        inputChannel = inputMessageChannel,
        processWork = ::processWork,
        logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ChannelUtilTest::class.java),
        nameOfWorkers = javaClass.simpleName,
        maxWorkers = 10,
        workerCounter = workerCounter
    )

    charPool.forEach {
        inputMessageChannel.send(it)
    }
    delay(20)

    assertEquals(26, count.get())
    assertEquals(10, workerCounter.get())
}
```

How can I test it correctly without adding the `delay(20)` after the forEach?

Comment: Coroutines are cheap to launch, why do you need this logic to dynamically start new ones instead of just launch `maxWorker` coroutines to process all elements right from the start?

Comment: Also `inputMessageChannel` and `workerCounter` are not defined in your test

Comment: @Joffrey what is a better way to get a max of x workers doing x functionality? The input channel is in the real code getting a lot of messages from a queue

Comment: You could just launch `maxWorker` coroutines which grab items from the input channel, process them, and output them to the output channel, without dynamic creation of coroutines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the reason why your current test doesn't work is that, without `delay()`, you don't wait for the worker coroutines (launched by `dispatchWorkConcurrently`) to finish. And this is hard to do with your current general design.

The design of `dispatchWorkConcurrently` doesn't really allow you to wait because it breaks structured concurrency by creating a new job (`SupervisorJob`) outside of the hierarchy (no parent job is specified).

Usually, you should strive for making suspend functions at the low level instead of using `CoroutineScope` receivers and launching coroutines in those externally-provided scopes. You can decompose concurrent work by using `supervisorScope { ... }` and launching coroutines locally in it, but your general function still waits for everything.

Also, as I mentioned in the comments, coroutines are cheap, so you don't really need to dynamically launch them when you detect all workers are busy. You could just launch `maxWorkers` coroutines right from the beginning.

All in all, it could look like this:

```kotlin
suspend fun <INPUT_TYPE, OUTPUT_TYPE> dispatchWorkConcurrently(
    inputChannel: ReceiveChannel<INPUT_TYPE>,
    processMessage: suspend (INPUT_TYPE, SendChannel<OUTPUT_TYPE>) -> Unit,
    logger: Logger,
    nameOfWorkers: String,
    maxWorkers: Int,
): ReceiveChannel<OUTPUT_TYPE> = supervisorScope {

    val outputChannel = Channel<OUTPUT_TYPE>()

    val coroutineExceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, throwable ->
        logger.error("Exception in $nameOfWorkers: ${throwable.localizedMessage}")
    }

    repeat(maxWorkers) { workerNum ->
        launch(coroutineExceptionHandler + CoroutineName("$nameOfWorkers $workerNum")) {
            for (msg in inputChannel) {
                processMessage(msg, outputChannel)
            }
        }
    }

    outputChannel
}
```

This means `dispatchWorkConcurrently` now waits for all child coroutines to finish, so the callers needs to call it in a coroutine if they want to do things concurrently with it. Your test could become:

```kotlin
@Test
fun `correctly dispatch jobs with multipele workers`() = runBlocking {
    val charPool : List<Char> = ('a'..'z').toList()
    val count = AtomicInteger(0)

    suspend fun processMessage(message: Char, output: SendChannel<String>) {
        delay(1)
        println("Does some work with: $message")
        count.getAndIncrement()
    }

    val job = launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
        dispatchWorkConcurrently(
            inputChannel = inputMessageChannel,
            processMessage = ::processMessage,
            logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ChannelUtilTest::class.java),
            nameOfWorkers = javaClass.simpleName,
            maxWorkers = 10,
        )
    }

    charPool.forEach {
        inputMessageChannel.send(it)
    }
    inputMessageChannel.close()
    job.join()

    assertEquals(26, count.get())
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Had to edit a couple of things like adding: `inputMessageChannel.close()` before `job.join()` otherwise it will block it. Also the return required the `return@supervisorScope outputChannel` instead of a normal return.

Comment: You could actually drop the `return` keyword entirely a the end, the last expression in `supervisorScope` is the returned value

Comment: Regarding the `close()` call, good point I had forgotten it. I edited the answer